# How to mock an EventEmitter on `createReadStream`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I'm trying to write a test case for when an error is emitted as a result of this code:

```
s3.getObject({
    Bucket: mediaBucket,
    Key: mediaId,
  }).createReadStream()
```

I've got a test with a dummy S3 object, and I'm using MemoryStream to cover cases where the call is successful. How do I emit an error, so I can write a test that allows me to test the behavior in `.on('error') function(error)..`?

Here's what I've tried, without success:

```
beforeEach(function () {
   var emitter = new EventEmitter;
   const s3 = {
     getObject: () => {
       return { createReadStream: () => emitter.emit('error', new Error('Random error!')) }
     },
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just emit it like you would any other event:

```
stream.emit('error', new Error('Random error!'));
```

So, the above code should look like:

```
const s3 = {
  getObject: () => {
    return { createReadStream: () => {
      process.nextTick(function() {
        emitter.emit('error', new Error('whoops!'));
      });
      return emitter;
    } }
  },
};
```

Comment: I updated my question to show exactly what I'm doing. I'm attempting to emit an error, I'm just clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to *return* the emitter first. Then use `process.nextTick()`/`setImmediate()` to emit the error, as that will give time for the caller to attach the `error` event handler.